# Free, trial app on Google Play, full version on my own website

Tags: web, google-play, trial, android

As a Hungarian software developer, up to this day it is **not possible** to sell apps on Google Play, because Hungary is not on the **[merchant list](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/150324?hl=en)**, therefore only free apps are allowed to upload from Hungary.

Is it possible and legal to upload the free trial version of my app to Google Play, and when the trial expires, through an intentional and unequivocal notification / window redirect the user **to my own website**, where she / he, after the payment process, can get the full version?

I'm also planning to put the link of the full version app to the Google Play app description section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post a free trial version of your app in Google Play and when the trial expires then they will be required to download a license file from your website.

This file will only remove the trail and let user use the app. You can add a notification when after 7 or so days of trial to purchase license. when they press okay then they would be directed to your website and download the license apk file after they pay.

And then after you post an updated version of your app in Google play. They will be able to update too and they will not loose their full version of the app.

Please make sure that you describe your app correctly in google play, and state that your app is free only for some days. and do not post a link to a full version app in your description if you are planning to host it on your website.

You can also integrate in-app purchase with the help of Paypal. [This documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/) teaches you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad! Did you do that / have you a situation like mine? Is it legally acceptable?

Comment: since i live in US, i don't have to do that, but yes, i have trial app in google play, then i also have  a license file that people can buy in google play.

Comment: I am not sure if its legal, but have you tried sponsorpay? or paypal?

Comment: PayPal is available in Hungary, but how do you mean PayPal? In-app payment?

Comment: take a look at [this documentation/tutorial](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/) of how to integrate paypal in your android app

Comment: I'll check PayPal and try your suggestion

Comment: awesome, then why don't you go ahead and accept my answer and/or upvote. It was a pleasure assisting you.

Answer (score 0):

You should get legal advice from a lawyer but I would say this is against the Google Play terms.

https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html

> 3.3 You may also choose to distribute Products for free. If the Product is free, you will not be charged a Transaction Fee. You may not collect future charges from users for copies of the Products that those users were initially allowed to download for free. This is not intended to prevent distribution of free trial versions of the Product with an "upsell" option to obtain the full version of the Product: Such free trials for Products are encouraged. **However, if you want to collect fees after the free trial expires, you must collect all fees for the full version of the Product through the Payment Processor on the Market.** In this Agreement, "free" means there are no charges or fees of any kind for use of the Product. All fees received by Developers for Products distributed via the Market must be processed by the Market's Payment Processor.

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer

Comment: Thank you Ken! What if I just upload a free, core functionality app without trial period, but when the user wants the full or pro version, redirect to my homepage?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try finding out from Google! They actually do respond, after a while. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/#contact=1

Answer (score 0):

Updating would be a problem then.
Or you could put the paid version for free and block some of the paid components, then you could enable the paid component if the user has paid, you need to make a web service for that.

I am not sure,I think even in-app purchases are supposed to be through Play Store

Comment: Thanks! My own website will take care the updating process.